# Can I both compile and add my dbml file as a resource?

Tags: visual-studio, linq-to-sql

I have created custom build and compile actions for our dbml files. The "Build Action" is set to "dbml" and I was wondering if it is possible to inside the project somehow also embed the dbml file as a resource. The reason for this is that I want to run smoke tests at application startup where the dbml file is validated against the production db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dbml file itself is not embedded by default, it is only used at design-time to generate the cs classes. However, the [mapping namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.aspx) allows you to traverse tables, members etc at runtime.

I guess you could embed the dbml file as a resource too, but since the mapping info is already there in the form of attributes on generated classes and members, and easily accessible through the mapping namespace that is an easier option.

Comment: Correct, I could validate that the problem is though that I removed all the generated classes and DataContexts from VCS because the dbml file dictates what will be generated anyway. We were spending way to much time merging things so I thought since I want to do this in TeamCity or equivalent I need to validate the dbml file. I'd rather reuse this functionality if possible :) Question remains: Can I both embedd the dbml file and use code generation at build time?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer though, I actually didn't consider that possibility!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Removed the generated classes from where? If they're not part of your app then how can you use them?

Comment: I removed them from version control system. I want to validate the dbml file before the build starts as a prerequisite. All the classes are regenerated for every build, even within Visual Studio. I want to reuse that for validating production if possible. 

To be precise I want to add the dbml file as a resource AND generate the classes at the same time.

Maybe I should reconsider and use the generated files for validation...

Comment: There is no need to embed the DBML just to be used as part of the build process - you can just script using sqlmetal.exe to convert the DBML to CS files as part of the build process.

The CS files will need to have been compiled in before runtime happens so as KristoferA says you'd be better off using the mapping namespace as it it provides strongly typed access to the information that was in the DBML :)

Comment: I am actually using our own gode generator based on http://ulinqgen.codeplex.com/. Tried to use your T4 templates DamienG but never could get it to work with our SP only solution. I guess I could solve it using a bit of reflection love.

Thanks guys, you have both done this before me with great success so I'll take your words for it. :)